# laravel-dompdf generate multiple page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

I use laravel-dompdf to generate my receipt, it should only generate one page, but it will generate 5 pages with the style of my CSS, the information will become messes. This was the example that i have generate https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzPkl.jpg. I also include my controller and view for dompdf

Controller

```
public function downloadReceiptPDF($id)
{

    $campaigns = DB::table('bill')
        ->select('bill.b_id', 'c_code', 'c_name', 'b_fee', 'b_date', 'total_month')
        ->join('campaign', 'campaign.c_id', '=', 'bill.c_id')
        ->where('bill.b_id', $id)
        ->get();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('campaign.receiptpdf', compact('campaigns'))->setPaper('a4', 'potrait');
    return $pdf->download('receipt.pdf');

}
```

View : receiptpdf.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        .invoice-box {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 30px;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #555;
        }

        .invoice-box table {
            width: 100%;
            line-height: inherit;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .invoice-box table td {
            padding: 5px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2) {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title {
            font-size: 45px;
            line-height: 45px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.heading td {
            background: #eee;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.details td {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.item td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.item.last td {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2) {
            border-top: 2px solid #eee;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        /** RTL **/

        .rtl {
            direction: rtl;
            font-family: Tahoma, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .rtl table {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .rtl table tr td:nth-child(2) {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="invoice-box">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="top">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="title">

                            </td>

                            <td>
                                Receipt #: {{ $campaigns[0]->b_id }}
                                <br> Date: {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($campaigns[0]->b_date)->format('d/m/Y') }}
                                <br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="information">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="heading">
                <td>
                    Campaign Code
                </td>

                <td>
                    Price
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item last">
                <td>
                    {{ $campaigns[0]->c_code }} ({{ $campaigns[0]->total_month }} months)
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{ $campaigns[0]->b_fee }}
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="total">
                <td></td>

                <td>
                    Total: RM {{ $campaigns[0]->b_fee }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not seeing the same issue. Which version of laravel-dompdf and Dompdf are you using? Can you provide the HTML being injested by Dompdf instead of the PHP that generates the HTML?

Comment: @BrianS "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5", the view that i provide was the html that used by Dompdf, sorry if i was wrong

Comment: You're not necessarily wrong, but if we can't reproduce then it's hard to provide feedback on how to address the issue (if possible). It could be something in the output, right now you've provided the template but if there's anything significant in one of the template vars then it could be causing the issue.